mysqlbinlog command giving error file not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
I am trying to read the binarylog file generated by mysql. While file is present in the folder, the command gives the error. I can open it with notepad, but it is not human readable. I am on Windows 11, mysql version 8.0.
Earlier it could not open with notepad, but then I changed the file permission so now can open in notepad. I stopped and started the mysql server, restarted the PC. Ran the command as administrator. I copied the file in another drive and then ran command as an administrator (also as regular user). But still the issue persists.
I disabled the anti-virus software to check if that might be giving the issue, but to no avail.
Attaching the error image for reference (error image is taken when executed on D drive folder where the log file was copied, the same logs were generated on C drive)

